# Is there a way to solve the equation $\frac{10x} {\sqrt{x^2+25}}-\frac{7(8-x)}{\sqrt{(8-x)^2+9}}=0$ for $x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, systems-of-equations

> Is there a way to solve the equation $$\frac{10x}
>  {\sqrt{x^2+25}}-\frac{7(8-x)}{\sqrt{(8-x)^2+9}}=0$$ for $x$?

I have tried various ways, but I just can't seem to find the $x$ value. When graphing the equation, I can see the $x$-intercept is $3.56$, but I want to find it algebraically. I have not learned the bisecting method, which is why I can not use that. When I cross multiply, I get $x =3.29$, which is not right.

Comment: Please use *MathJax*.  Your "equation" is not an equation, and hence unclear.

Comment: Hint: Your equation is of the form $A-B=0$, from which you can deduce that $A=B$ and hence $A^2=B^2$. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: "*When I cross multiply, I get $x=3.29$*" $\;$ Recheck your calculations. You should be getting $\,51 x^4 - 816 x^3 + 2939 x^2 + 19600 x - 78400 = 0\,$ which is a [quartic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) with a positive real root $\,\approx 3.56\,$.

Comment: How do you simplify a quartic function? Did you use synthetic division?

Comment: @confusedcalcstudent How did *you* "cross multiply"?

Comment: I am not familiar with the quartic formula, can you elaborate?

Comment: @confusedcalcstudent Quartics are solvable by radicals, and this is well explained at the previous [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots), including the actual formulas. But the calculations are laborious, and the end result is not pretty in the case of your quartic - just look at the expression posted in an answer below.

Comment: Could you say if the origin of your equation is a path minimization problem (optics ?) between a point (0,5) and a point (8,-3), crossing at (x,0) an interface between two regions where the resp. speed of motion are $v_1,v_2$ ? If yes there are alternate ways of solving...

Comment: @JeanMarie. This is a more than interesting remark.

Comment: Could you answer my question ? Is it understandable ?

Answer (score 4):

As already said in comments, you need to solve $$51 x^4-816 x^3+2939 x^2+19600 x-78400=0$$ and you found that the solution is close to $x=\frac 72$. So, let $x=y+\frac 72$ to make
$$816 y^4-1632 y^3-30088 y^2+302904 y-18081=0$$ So, ignoring for the time being the high powers
$$302904 y-18081=0 \implies y=\frac{287}{4808}$$ Make  $y=z+\frac{287}{4808}$
$$27253859460919296 z^4-48000349815945216 z^3-1014097664036020096 z^2+$$ $$ 9996261833745003040
   z-3591931811028925=0$$
$$9996261833745003040
   z-3591931811028925=0\implies z=\frac{102626623172255}{285607480964142944}$$  At this point, we have
$$x=\frac 72+\frac{287}{4808}+\frac{102626623172255}{285607480964142944}=\frac{1016777343075191075}{285607480964142944}=3.560051507$$ while the solution is $x=3.560051520$

*This step-by-step procedure is exactly the way Newton invented Newton method*

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* gives a rather complex solution, suggesting you don't want to try this by hand:

$$x = \frac{1}{102} \left(408-\sqrt{17 \left(3914+\sqrt[3]{219708502019-151200
   \sqrt{2083305494323}}+\sqrt[3]{219708502019+151200
   \sqrt{2083305494323}}\right)}+\sqrt{17 \left(7828-\sqrt[3]{219708502019-151200
   \sqrt{2083305494323}}-\sqrt[3]{219708502019+151200 \sqrt{2083305494323}}+306000
   \sqrt{\frac{17}{3914+\sqrt[3]{219708502019-151200
   \sqrt{2083305494323}}+\sqrt[3]{219708502019+151200
   \sqrt{2083305494323}}}}\right)}\right)$$

Which has numerical value $x = 3.56005$.